# Como escrever várias string (nomes) em R?

Tags: r, string

A exemplo estou querendo escrever uma seguencia de nome
`nome<-c[scan("")]`

```
#insirindo uma sequencia de numeros
  idade<-scan()
  1: 45
  2: 65
  3: 12
  4: 32
  5: 23
  6: 78
  7: 87
  8: 98
  9: 12
  10: 555
  11:    #tecle enter para parar
 #verificando valores 
 idade
 [1] 1: 45 65 12 32 23 78 87 98 12 555
```

Answer (score 0):

Você na verdade quer criar um vetor?!

```
nome <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
```

Comment: é um vetor de string como no exemplo :  idade<-scan()

Comment: Você quer transformar isto em um data frame?

Comment: Acho que consegui : nome<-scan(what = character())

Comment: Testei aqui, não vi diferença quanto a estrutura. O uso do `scan`, pelo que vi, apenas lhe proporciona que você digite as suas palavras de interesse no console, mas se feito isto e vc fizer `View(nome)` poderá ver que é o mesmo resultado utilizando o `c` para criação de vetor.